# Naming Boolean columns in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have a `Dog` and I want to store if it is `trained` in Rails. Conventionally, Ruby methods that return booleans have names that end with `?`. **Should I call the database column `trained?`, or should I call the database column `trained` and have a method**

```
class Dog
  def trained?
    trained
  end
end
```

The latter option seems inefficient, particularly when I have lots of boolean fields.

Or is there some other alternative I'm missing?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You should call it `trained`. Define it in your schema with a type of `:boolean`. You can refer to it as `trained?` and everything will magically work.

So says http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/60847