# rails boolean fields: `is_foo` or just `foo`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, convention

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Naming Boolean columns in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524154/naming-boolean-columns-in-rails)

What is the rails convention regarding names of boolean fields?

For example, if I have a `User` model that needs a flag for its "activeness", should I call the db field `is_active` or `active` ?

Note: Rails automatically generates question-marked methods for accessing boolean fields: `User.is_active?` and `User.active?`.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The plain-adjective form is easily the norm in Ruby and Rails — `even?`, `nil?`, `empty?` and `blank?` for example. The only method of the form `is_#{something}?` that I can think of is `Kernel#is_a?` to determine class identity. So to stick with standard naming conventions, I would leave off the `is_` on boolean methods like this.

Comment: thanks I appreciate your comment. However I believe `is_xxx` will be more appropiate for my application. I've run up to a boolean called `is_client`. Replacing it by `client` makes it look like an ActiveRecord association (eventhough I don't have a Client model on my design... for now).

Comment: I think what Chuck has eluded to here is the inclusion of the question mark. It would be `client?` (including the question mark) not `client` or `is_client`. The `is_` prefix is for languages that don't support adding a question mark to the name. To define it is simply: `def client? ... end`

Comment: Also, Rails creates corresponding methods for boolean values. So if you have a field called client that is a boolean then Rails will creates a method on that model called `client?` that allows you to check if it's set.

Comment: Besides it being the norm, one advantage of avoiding the `is_` prefix if you are using RSpec is that [predicate matchers](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/predicate-matchers) will read much better. E.g., `expect(user).to be_active`

Comment: to be fair `is_a?` is not `is_"something"` because `a` it's just the article, not the object.. hence why it's allowed :P

Answer (score 9):

Of the 2 you should choose the one that sounds better to you: User.active? or User.is_active?

I'd personally opt for the former.

The question mark goody comes from Ruby, not Rails.

Comment: Your gave me the solution to my problem - I ended up using what I thought was most correct (`is_client`). Chuck however answered the question - Rails (and Ruby) seem to favour the plain-adjective. I would share the answer between the two of you if I could. I can only give you a +1 and my thanks. Also, thanks for the pointers regarding the question mark - I didn't know it came from ruby itself.

Comment: I really hate "follow your heart" answers. Non-answers, really.

Comment: I choose the later than the former.  User.active to me could be a named scope. For me it's just more clear that .active is a scope and .is_active is a boolean.  Yeah you have the ? on the method, but: User.active, user.active?, user.is_active? -- the last one is just easier to contextually recognize, imho.

Comment: One alternative is to split the baby.  Name the field `is_active`, but add your own boolean methods for interrogation.  I like having both a positive and a negative, so I'd define `active?` and `inactive?`.  If I need to set the value, I use `is_managed=`, but I try to always use the `active?` or `inactive?` forms as appropriate in expressions.

Comment: @Arcolye Programming is a kind of art, ie it requires a lot of creativity and it is your responsibility as a programmer to write nice looking code. So where there is no naming convention you just have to _follow your heart_. +1